# Given $E[e^{tX}]=e^{t^2}$, find $E[X^2]$

Tags: statistics, expected-value

I tried approaching it from the variance perspective, ie
$$\operatorname{var}(X)=e^{t^2}(1-e^{t^2})$$
and then I thought that maybe I should take the integral from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ of the pdf, but that's not really the right approach either.

I think I'm missing some kind of algebraic manipulation here, if someone wouldn't mind pointing me in the right direction...thanks!

Comment: Hint: what is the second derivative of $E[e^{tX}]$ with respect to $t$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Among others, there are two ways to solve this. First, note that for any random variable X whose moment generating function (MGF) exists, $E(X^2) = \frac{d^2}{dt^2} E(e^{tX})|_{t = 0}$. In words, the second moment is the second derivative of the MGF evaluated at 0. Hence, using this approach, and since you know the form of the MGF, we have

$$
E(X^2) = \frac{d^2}{dt^2} E(e^{tX})|_{t = 0} = \frac{d^2}{dt^2}e^{t^2} = \left(2e^{t^2} + 4t^2 e^{t^2}\right)|_{t = 0} = 2.
$$
Another way is if you know the MGF of the normal distribution. Indeed for a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, the MGF is $E(e^{tX}) = e^{\mu t + \sigma^2 t^2 /2}$. So you could view your $E(e^{tX})$ as the MGF of a normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $2$. Thus, $E(X^2) = Var(X) = 2$. Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks! this was very clear